# Using Bayesian statistics in time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, panel-data, hierarchical-bayesian, kalman-filter, filter

I would like to forecast demand count time series of taxi fleets at different locations on the map at different points in time. I.e. multivariate demand Time series forecasting.

Given hierarchinal demand time series. where the region level time series is the sum of district level time series at each point in time and district level time is the sum of city level time series at each point. sum of all the city level time series at each point in time should equal region level time series. There are also covariate time series (both numerical and categorical) associated with each city's demand time series. e.g. rainfall level, temperature, traffic level, taxi supply amount, date information like weekday or weekend, holiday information and Time invariant features like type of city. (e.g. industrial, CBD, residential etc. )

How do I go about using a bayesian framework/statistics to model and predict the mutivariate  (city-wide) demand time series?

The reason for choosing the bayesian framework is to

1. estimate uncertainty in the prediction.
2. Build a strong prior sequentially over time which can capture the fundamental data distribution/patterns without being affected by noise in instantaneous data.
3. incorporate the various pieces of covariate information together to enhance prediction accuracy.

Here are my thoughts:

- Use summary statistics of covariate time series and response time series like ACF to compare similiarities between and try to explain causation.
- Try to improve dataset quality by (probably using bayesian a hierarchical model using partial pooling) to combine sparse and low quality (lowly correlated time series to response time series) covariates to model a better covariate.
- Use bayesian sequential learning to sequentially accumulate learned patterns over time into the prior distribution.

Could someone give me your thoughts and suggestions on how to go about doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/123874/73930)

Comment: It's also pretty broad. It's asking someone to do an entire project without providing any notation, data or code.

Comment: Have you looked into [Bayesian structural time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/361553)?

Comment: @Durden Thanks for your reply. I will take a look at this. There is a simple tutorial on BSTS here: https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/. This requires fitting a seperate model for each time series. I would like to model this entire  system and capture their interaction/correlation effects as well which I believe will help to improve prediction accuracy. Is BSTS helpful in that regard?

Comment: @Durden Do you think if it is possible to create a bayesian hierarchical model for this entire system and then update it sequentially in time with new data? Thanks.

Comment: @Taylor I am just asking for suggestions from someone with experience in this kind of a design as I am doing it first time. I want to know if such an approach is possible in the first place. Do you think if it is possible to create a bayesian hierarchical model for this entire system and then update it sequentially in time with new data? Thanks.